# Django admin select fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have 2 models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    some fields in model...

class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    some fields in model...
```

I want to show in admin panel 2 select fields:

1. with groups
2. with persons for active(selected) group in first select field

How to do this fields? How to show persons related with active group?

Comment: You want dynamic options in **person** dropdown based on the selection in **group** dropdown ?

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140223/1923614)