# limit the choices for objects related to the chosen in the select

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I wonder if anyone would know a way to return the categories related to the session chosen in the select options.

Example:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Sessão", max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug", max_length=100)

class Category(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, verbose_name='Sessão', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField("Categoria", max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug", max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Categoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, verbose_name='Sessão', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

When registering an Article, I would define a session for the article, and then I would like to return categories, only the categories related to that session.

Can anybody help me ?
I believe this would have to be dynamically ...

Strong hug!

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution:**

Override the template ([Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options) can help you with that)

Onchange of the field, you need to make an ajax call to an API which takes in session_id and returns you all the categories. Fill the returned result into categories through JS.

Also, you can give a try to [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)

**2nd solution:** (without JS/AJAX)

To register an article, You can first go to session admin and then have a link there to add an article.

a.
If you want to do it changeform_view then, 
You can use inline admin and override its form init() to prepopulate the categories.

b.
If you want the link in changelist_view,

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/<app>/article/add/?session_id=<>
```

You can override the Article Admin form init() and read the session_id passed and use it accordingly.